# how to add content to a menu

Tags: nodes, routes

I want to publish a node to a custom menu page like "people" rather than the front page "Home." I tried many ways, but I cannot deal with this matter.

Could somebody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the standard method of creating menus and adding nodes to menus?  Take a look at [Working with Menus](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu).

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a menu item for this node when you edit the node under the "Menu settings" when you click on "Provide a menu link" it will allow you to provide menu link title where you can specify like "people" and you can choose parent menu item of this menu item. Under "publishing options" you can uncheck " Promoted to front page" option to prevent this node being published at front page.